# wordpress rounded boxes around each individual widget

Tags: css, wordpress, styling

I am working on creating a theme and need to know how to make a rounded box around each individual widget. I want to change each color. I need it rounded also and dynamic. I need if i add more things it will stretch or auto adjust the height.  I have tried over and over but unable to find a good way. Here is my test board

http://wpcreations.net/wptest/

I have right now a box. I need it to be rounded off and this has to be cross browser compatible. Thank you in advance.

I

Comment: Which browsers are you supporting? Specifically, which browsers *must* you have rounded corners in?

Comment: It has to be IE 7 - 9 , FF and chrome.

Comment: Well, you're looking at a complex CSS/html solution or a scripting solution. For sake of ease, I've used this before, with success - http://css3pie.com/

Comment: I am willing to pay because i can not get any method to work. I have 10 bucks paypal. Please include a way to get ahold of you.

Comment: As I tell my clients, I can round corners on anything for any browser....but it's a lot cheaper and quicker to round them only for the browsers that "behave".  That's the beauty of progressive enhancement such as JQuery UI supports:  rounded corners with two includes and a class tag that are done in minutes and gracefully degrade to square corners for those who refuse to update.  Users of IE DESERVE square corners for supporting that garbage browser!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish the rounded corners on each widget via `border-radius`.

In your theme's style sheet, add:

```
.widget { 
   border-radius:10px; 
   -moz-border-radius:10px; 
   -webkit-border-radius:10px; 
}
```

For the different background colors, you'll have to target each widget individually and specify a color for them in your style sheet.

And to make IE6-8 behave with rounded corners, you *could* use "[Curved Corners](http://www.htmlremix.com/css/curved-corner-border-radius-cross-browser)". It won't *necessarily* validate, but it'll get the look you want.

IE9 already supports `border-radius`, but you have to specify your meta tag properly:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

## //EDIT

To use [Curved Corners](http://www.htmlremix.com/css/curved-corner-border-radius-cross-browser), first download the [most updated version here](http://curved-corner.googlecode.com/files/border-radius.htc). 
Then all you should have to do is upload the `border-radius.htc` file to your server where you can get to it; generally in the css folder of your theme.
After that, wherever you want to have a border radius you add `behavior: url(border-radius.htc)` to the css.

Our example, with Curved Corners' `border-radius.htc` added:

```
.widget { 
   border-radius:10px; 
   -moz-border-radius:10px; 
   -webkit-border-radius:10px;
   behavior: url(http://path.to.file/border-radius.htc); 
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: yes i would need support on IE 6 , - IE 8. I do not understand how to use the curved corners. i have downloaded it but do not understand how i would link it or anything

Comment: I have added the mime type to my server and also here is the css     [code]     #l_sidebar #nav_menu-25 {
border-radius:10px; 
-moz-border-radius:10px; 
-webkit-border-radius:10px;  
behavior:url("http://wpcreations.net/wptest/border-radius.htc");

background: #EE1C25 none;
color: #EF000A;
font-weight: bold;
height:100px;
} [/code]

Comment: Added more information on Curved Corners' `border-radius.htc` to answer. See above.

Comment: I am willing to pay someone money to get this working. i have tried and tried. I even tried pie as mentioned above... if someone want to do this for 10 bucks please include way for me to get ahold of you.

Comment: Try putting in the absolute url into your behavior attribute. So, instead of `behavior:url(/border-radius.htc)` put in `url(http://wpcreations.net/wptest/border-radius.htc)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to not having rounded corners in IE6/7/8, then CSS alone will accomplish this:

```
.rounded_corners {
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Note that the `-moz-` and `-webkit-` properties are to support older Mozilla and Webkit browsers. The newest browsers, including IE9, support `border-radius` as it is.